# Example of convex and injective $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}$ is not concave

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

> Example of a convex and injective function $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ on an interval $I$, such that $f(I)$ is an interval and $f^{-1}:f(I)\to \mathbb{R}$ is not concave.

*Attempt*. Our function $f$ cannot be monotone (in that case, since $f(\mathbb{R})$ is an interval, $f$ would be continuous and it that case $f^{-1}$ would be concave if $f$ is strictly increasing and convex if $f$ is strictly decreasing).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: But convex functions on open sets are continuous.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Of course. I will substitute  the domain to  an interval $I$, instead of being the open set $\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $x \longmapsto e^{-x}$?